# How to use policy in laravel livewire (return, it is not a trait)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have category policy as below partial code.

```
class CategoryPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function view(User $user, Category $category)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then, I call from livewire component inside the mount method.

```
class Productcategorysetup extends Component
{
    use CategoryPolicy;
    public function mount()
    {
        $this->authorize('view',CategoryPolicy::class);  
    }
}
```

I got an error message

> App\Http\Livewire\Generalsetting\Productcategorysetup cannot use App\Policies\CategoryPolicy - it is not a trait

Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use authorization in Livewire, you need to import the `AuthorizesRequests` trait first, and use that in your class.

Secondly, the first argument to `authorize()` when using `view`, is the instance of a model - in your case, a category. But this sounds like you want to list categories, i.e. the "index" file - which means you want to check for `viewAny` (as `view` is for a specific resource). In that case, the second argument is the class-name of the model, rather than the instance of a model.

```
<?php 

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use App\Models\Category;

class Productcategorysetup extends Component
{
    use AuthorizesRequests;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->authorize('viewAny', Category::class);  
    }
}
```

Then in your policy,

```php
class CategoryPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function viewAny(User $user)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function view(User $user, Category $category)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Qirel, thanks. Anyway how can I specipy the specific policy with single method name (viewAny)? E.g. PoductPolicy, CategoryPolicy with same viewAny name.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the same logic for different policies? Well, you can abstract them into traits, but I would just re-write it the same way. Alternatively, you can define global gates and check for that.